# H2 Embedded Database foreign keys and references

Tags: java, database, jpa, relationship

So, I have a homework where I need to implement two entities - Account and Transaction
Futher on I need to be able to create a transaction between two accounts (scenario: only 2 account involved)

I also need to find out table's structure for Transaction and would appreciate a help for Transaction table creation script.

**My question is:** I need to find out how to reference the foreign keys and relationship between these two tables as for now it is a bit unclear for me.

Logic is next: 
I was thinking and maybe an `Account` would have two `List<Transaction>` as in:

```
private List<Transaction> transactionsMade; 
private List<Transaction> transactionsReceived.
```

therefore:
in `Transaction` class would be:

`@ManyToOne` referencing the `transactionMadeList`

```
private Account emitter;
```

`@ManyToOne` referencing the `transactionReceivedList`

```
private Account receptor;
```

So here are my classes

Account.class

```
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String holder;

    @NotNull
    private Integer balance;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "emitter",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Transaction> transactionsMade;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "receptor",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Transaction> transactionsReceived;

}
```

Transaction.class

```
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private Integer amount;

    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "transactionEmitter")
    private Account emitter;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "transactionReceptor")
    private Account receptor;

    public Transaction(Integer amount, Account emitter, Account receptor){
        this.created = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.amount = amount;
        this.emitter = emitter;
        this.receptor = receptor;
    }

}
```

For now that's it.

Thank You in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking in the right direction. Here is how your schema will look like:
[image: database schema]

The only two things I noticed you could do better:

> 1) Use `Instant` instead of `LocalDateTime`, so it will be stored in UTC time.

Change this:

```
private LocalDateTime created;
```

To this:

```
private Instant created;
```

> 2) Do not use `EAGER` initialization:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "emitter",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Transaction> transactionsMade;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "receptor",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Transaction> transactionsReceived;
```

will become this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "emitter",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Transaction> transactionsMade;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "receptor",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Transaction> transactionsReceived;
```

If you get famous `LazyInitializationException`, try wrapping it around `@Transactional`. It might complicate it a bit, however, in the long run, will save you some server resources, because you won't be loading all account's transaction when they are not even needed.

> 3) Create a repository to modularize your functionality, just like this one:

```
@Repository
public interface TransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transaction, Long> {
    Collection<Transaction> findAllByEmitter(Account emitter);
    Collection<Transaction> findAllByReceptor(Account receptor);
}
```

Comment: Holy moly big spasibo buddy, I was struggling a bit with foreign keys and relationships within of this specific case. Thank you so much for clarifying it for me :)

Comment: Btw Ilya, what tool did you use for designing tables?

Comment: @PaveS I used draw.io